# Query returning multiple errors in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax-error

```
Emp_id  Emp_Name    Dept_ID Dept_Name salary
1   a   AA  IT  2000       100
2   b   AA  IT  3000       200
3   c   AA  IT  4000       300
4   d   BB  HR  1000       400
5   e   BB  HR  2000       500
6   f   BB  HR  3000       600
7   g   BB  HR  4000       700
8   h   CC  FI  2500       800
9   i   CC  FI  3500       900
```

This is my table structure.I want to find out the `emp_id` & `dept_id` whose salary is greater than the average salary in its group. I have tried a sql query but is showing error

```
select Emp_id 
from dbo.Sheet1$ 
where Salary >= (select AVG(Salary) from dbo.Sheet1$ group by Dept_ID)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: And **WHAT ERROR** are you getting?!?? We can't see your screen, nor can we read your mind - please **post** the complete and exact error message(s) you're getting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Emp_id,Dept_ID from (
  select Emp_id, Emp_Name, 
  avg(salary) over (partition by dept_id) avg_sal 
  from yourtable
) a
where salary > avg_sal
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT Emp_id 
FROM dbo.Sheet1$ A
where A.Salary >= (SELECT AVG(B.Salary) FROM dbo.Sheet1$ B WHERE B.Dept_ID=A.Dept_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
      tbl.Emp_id,
      AVG(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.Dept_ID) AS avgSalery
  FROM
      dbo.Sheet1$ AS tbl
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.Sheet1$ AS tbl
    JOIN CTE
        ON CTE.Emp_id=tbl.Emp_id
        AND tbl.salary>=CTE.avgSalery
```

Answer (score 0):

Without error msg difficult, but one thing i can tell you: Your second select, the AVG is grouped by  so it can return multiple values, so the > is not a valid operator.